# QNX Neutrino sound card not working

Tags: audio, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I have installed QNX 6.4.0 neutrino on an unused x86 box. It's all working fine, I can run my test code on there via the network connection (qconn).

However the sound does not work. When I click the audio settings I get an error, similarly if I run my code it can't find an audio card.

I had an on-board sound card (built-in). Running io-audio, I was not able to detect it. So I went a purchased a new off the shelf PCI sound card (CMI-8738), this also failed to be recognized by QNX.

When I run "pci -vvv | less" I am able to see both audio devices are connected (and I can see in the BIOS as well).

I read somewhere that I need to get some driver called deva-ctrl-cmpci.so, but I can't find that anywhere.

What can I do?

Comment: If this is off-topic, please let me know where I can post it, thanks : )

Comment: QNX support forum? http://community.qnx.com/sf/sfmain/do/home  Please spend some try and pick the most relevant forum to maximize your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I have added it to that forum, thanks... not sure how I close this question here?